# How to know the selected card style and pass the value to the backend

Tags: javascript, php, css, web

I want to get the value in a single card selected by the user and post it to the backend

[image]
[image]

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="swiper-container swipercards">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper pb-4">
      <div class="swiper-slide ">
        <div class="card border-0 bg-default text-white">
          <div class="card-header">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-auto">
                <i class="material-icons vm text-template">credit_card</i>
              </div>
              <div class="col pl-0">
                <h6 class="mb-1">Visa</h6>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="mb-0 mt-3">4444 5264 2541 26651</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <p class="mb-0">26/21</p>
                <p class="small ">Expiry date</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto align-self-center text-right">
                <p class="mb-0">Agnish Carvan</p>
                <p class="small">Card Holder</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide ">
        <div class="card border-0 bg-warning text-white">
          <div class="card-header">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-auto">
                <i class="material-icons vm text-template">credit_card</i>
              </div>
              <div class="col pl-0">
                <h6 class="mb-1">Maestro</h6>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="mb-0 mt-3">4444 5264 2541 26651</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <p class="mb-0">26/21</p>
                <p class="small ">Expiry date</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-auto align-self-center text-right">
                <p class="mb-0">Agnish Carvan</p>
                <p class="small">Card Holder</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome AegisFor. It looks like you're using Swiper.js?

According to the docs, under events, here is how you determine the selected item in the carousel:

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  // ...
});
swiper.on('slideChange', function () {
  console.log('slide changed', swiper.activeIndex);
});
```

https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#events

You could get the values by referring to the slide's attributes, like this:

```
....
    <div class="swiper-wrapper pb-4" >
      <div class="swiper-slide " id="card-1" data-card-number="12345">
....
```

When you change slides, refer to the div that matches the activeIndex of the carousel:

```
var activeCard = document.getElementById("card-" + swiper.activeIndex);
```

Now you can get the card number:

```
var cardNumber = activeCard.getAttribute("data-card-number")
```

How you send it to your backend depends on what backed you have. You might do something similar to this:

```
fetch('http://example.com/card?card-number=' + cardNumber)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
  });
```

The documentation at https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api is quite good. Remember to read the docs thoroughly before posting to SO.

Comment: ok, thank , I'm not good at front-end development
now, i go to try it

Comment: Everyone starts somewhere, good luck! Remember to upvote and mark as the accepted answer :)